# Unity 2D, I can not resolve it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a platformer game but when i created the fall animation it showed me this error CS1026 at : `if(Player, whatIsGround == 0){`

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterAnim : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator anim;

public LayerMask whatIsGround;

public float Player;


void Start(){
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update(){

    if(Player, whatIsGround == 0){

        anim.SetBool("Test", true);
    } else {
        anim.SetBool("Test", false);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        anim.SetBool("Left", true);
    } else {
        anim.SetBool("Left", false);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        anim.SetBool("Right", true);
    } else {
        anim.SetBool("Right", false);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }
}
}
```

How can i resolve it ?

Comment: What do you expect `if(Player, whatIsGround == 0)` to do? Can you elaborate what you´re trying to do here?

Comment: On all the platforms i put the tag whatIsGround and if the player didnt "see" the platform to make the Fall animation ( in this script  is named Test)

Comment: For better formatting, all code should be indented by 4 positions

Comment: First of: why is your player a float? I could imagine a player has a playernumber, but this pretty sure is just an `int`, not a `float`. I don´t get it. Anyway, I assume you want `if(player == 0 && whatIsGround == 0)` or `||` instead of `&&` or ... I don´t know.

Comment: How `Player, whatIsGround == 0` could ever be `true` or `false` ?

Comment: I also wonder what you store in Player variable. How how can you check if the player is grounded by a layermask. Also I believe you make a mistake because you say if left or right arrow are pressed, you set the boolean left and you again say right or left key pressed you set boolean right.

Answer (score 1):

According to the microsoft documentation ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1026)):

> Compiler Error CS1026
>
> ) expected
>
> An incomplete statement was found.

You have 2 mistakes here. First of all you can't convert float to bool like this and then you can't have ',' symbol between 2 statements in if structure.

I suggest to replace ',' with '&&' or '||' ([C# operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)) and make boolean expression with Player variable like this:

```
  if(Player > 0 && whatIsGround == 0)
```